# Restore the compare mini-window in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++ when you use compare, there's that miniwindow that shows and overview of changes across the whole document. I've closed that at some point - how do I restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. With your screen maximised, drag the right hand side adjust bar to the left.